# How can I change the icon of a marker in an OpenStreetMap widget?

Tags: thingsboard

Good afternoon! I need to change the icon of a marker in the map here with some JS code, but I don't know how can I achieve that using the *images* array.
I tried this but it doesn't work. Any help will be appreciated!

[image: My Code]

Comment: Does your image array contain more than one image? Otherwise it should be `images[0]` to access the first image

Comment: Thanks for the help. My array has 3 images. The problem was that I wasn't declaring the size of the image. After doing that. It worked like a charm. Thanks again

Comment: Would you mind sharing your solution as answer to your question for the next one having the same problem? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I wasn't declaring the size of the image. Here is the code that worked for me.

```
var res = {size: 40};
res.url =  images[1];

return res;
```